# PHP socket doesn't send

Tags: php, sockets, graphite

I am trying to send some plain text data to a graphite server running on my local, here's the code for the same:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 2003;

$fsock = fsockopen($address,$port);

for($i=1;;$i++){

  $send = "dummy.metric.value ".$i." ".time();
  $sent = fwrite($fsock, $send, strlen($send));
  echo $send ." sent ".$sent."\n";
  sleep(4);
}

?>
```

There are no errors but the graphite server doesn't show the new data. The server is running and I can send data through `nc` and `telnet`

Comment: It's possibly buffered, add a call to [`fflush()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php) (`fflush( $fsock);`) before `sleep(4);`.

Comment: @nickb did that, still the same.

Comment: Do you need to send a CRLF as well? Are you pressing return when you do it through telnet/nc? Try adding `."\r\n"` to the data you pass to `fwrite()`

Comment: @DaveRandom: wow! never thought that would be an issue. good catch! works now..

Comment: Sockets are a bit more low level. They need control characters to determine where your command starts and ends.

Answer (score 2):

Also don't forget to check carbon.conf, because the UDP listener is off by default.

This option fooled me, because apparently StatsD and Graphite are communicating using TCP on the same host. I tested inserting metric with

```
echo "test.foo 20 `date +%s`" | nc 192.168.10.10 2003
```

But after reading the man pages, it turns out you have to add -u to nc to force it using UDP.

Hope this saves other people some time.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a TCP stream - but [graphite uses UDP](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/087fde9f3e52c4f76cc28b3d9bf986e0a3a3ae49/examples/php-example.php) ?

Comment: on using udp, it throws connection refused errors. But the question was solved, please read the comments above.