# PHP silently fails sending data to graphite over UDP using fsockopen and fwrite

Tags: php, udp, graphite

### The code

I'm sending metrics to [graphite](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web) via UDP using both php and python.

My **python** client looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
from socket import socket

sock = socket()
try:
  sock.connect( ('127.0.0.1', 2003) )
except:
  print 'network error'
  sys.exit(12)

message = ("some.custom.metric.python 1 %d\n" % (int( time.time() )))
print message
sock.sendall(message)
```

Output:

> some.custom.metric.python 1 1376045467

And my **php** client like this

```
<?php

try {
    $fp = fsockopen("udp://127.0.0.1", 2003, $errno, $errstr);

    if (!empty($errno)) echo $errno;
    if (!empty($errstr)) echo $errstr;

    $message = "some.custom.metric.php 1 ".time().PHP_EOL;
    $bytes = fwrite($fp, $message);
    echo $message;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "\nNetwork error: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Output:

> some.custom.metric.php 1 1376042961

### Testing

I start **carbon** enabling debug output:

```
/opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py --debug start
```

When I run my **python** client it works just fine, and I can see it on the debug output

```
09/08/2013 13:13:05 :: [listener] MetricLineReceiver connection with 127.0.0.1:58134 established
09/08/2013 13:13:05 :: [listener] MetricLineReceiver connection with 127.0.0.1:58134 closed cleanly
```

I do the same via CLI using **netcat**

```
echo "some.custom.metric.netcat 1 `date +%s`" | nc -w 1 127.0.0.1 2003
```

And I can see the connection in the debug output

> ```
> 09/08/2013 13:17:46 :: [listener] MetricLineReceiver connection with 127.0.0.1:58136 established
> 09/08/2013 13:17:48 :: [listener] MetricLineReceiver connection with 127.0.0.1:58136 closed cleanly
> ```

### The problem

My php client is never communicating with carbon. Even if I use a different port where there's no app listening my PHP just tells me everything's fine. if I do the same on my python client I get a network error.

According to the PHP docs, fsockopen **never** fails when using UDP because of the nature of the protocol, but I should get an error when executing the **fwrite**. In my case the fwrite always returns the len() of the $message no matter which host/port I use when opening the socket.

If I use a wrong port with netcat or the python client i get a network error as expected.

PHP-cli has `error_display = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL`. I've tested this on PHP 5.4.4-14 on debian 7.1 and PHP 5.5 on Windows 7.

Has anybody run into something similar to this? I'm almost sure there's no problem with my graphite or network configurations, so I bet it has something to do with PHP.

Comment: Can't really reproduce the issue. But have you tried setting a timeout for `fsockopen` ?

Comment: @tienss which php version and OS did you use? Did you get an error when executing the fwrite? I tried using a timeout, it doesn't change the fact that fwrite keeps working like nothing  wrong is happening :/

Comment: I'll have a look at the actual code .. OS: debian squeeze (2.6.32-5) PHP: 5.3.23

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP socket doesn't send](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913546/php-socket-doesnt-send)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have an open UDP port (it's off by default). The code (simplified version) i used for testing (uses TCP)

```
$line = "foo.bla 1 " . time() . "\n";

$fp = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 2003, $err, $errc, 1);
fwrite($fp, $line);

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: fsockopen will always fail when connecting to a port that is not opened if you're using TCP, but not if you're using UDP.

Comment: Sure! But have you checked that there is actually a open UDP port (2003) on your system?

Comment: Yes I have, and you can see that I can send data through my custom python tool or netcat, my only problem is using php...

Comment: In Python you are using TCP... in PHP you are using UDP

Comment: Damn, you're right, even using netcat I'm doing it via TCP! D: Thanks for insistnig on it!

Comment: I was away on vacation. I came home checked and lo and behold, `ENABLE_UDP_LISTENER` was set to `False` on `/opt/graphite/conf/carbon.conf` I changed it to `True`, restarted carbon-cache and everything worked. Thanks a bunch @tlenss !

As for PHP not failing when doing an `fwrite` to an invalid resource, I can't figure out why the weird behaviour :/